# download unknown file from Url

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In my application I need to download a .fec file from an Url and save it to another location.
I am using the C# Web Client for this. 
But when I try to download a .fec file(we cannot view this file in IE or FF) Its downloading 
404 page not found file and saving it to myfolder.
I dont know why its downloading a 404 page not found file when the file is existing at specified location.
 Is this because .Fec files require a separate program to view it(you need Fec Viewer in order to view .fec files).
If I download a .txt file or .pdf file my program is working fine. I am able to download the 
file and save it to my folder.

Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code

```
 public void downloadFile(string url, string saveas)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.WebClient webclient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                webclient.DownloadFile(url, saveas);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.ErrorLog(e.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up that `extension/mime-type` in IIS or add a wilcard for serving unknown file types. By default, IIS won't serve 'unknown files'.

**IIS6** - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965
**IIS7** - http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the info. Not sure what is the mime type for .fec. so added mime type as text like following <mimeMap fileExtension=".fec" mimeType="text/plain" />. Still not working any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Does a regular browser at least let you download the file if it can't display it directly?  If not, then my guess is that your web server is not configured correctly.  If the server doesn't have a MIME type associated with that file extension it can prevent the file from being downloaded.